# Rails Associations - Creating a new record through a form with belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have a Course model:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sub_courses

  validates :title, presence: true

  # Course associated to SubCourse via 'sub_course_id' on Course table
end
```

And a SubCourse model:

```
class SubCourse < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course

  # SubCourse associated to Course via 'course_id' on SubCourse table
end
```

On the `courses.show.html` (specific course page e.g. admin/courses/1) I have a button that links to a new sub course page

```
%table
  %tr
    %td= @course.title
    %td= @course.description

= button_to "Add New Sub Course", new_admin_sub_course_path(course_id: @course.id), method: :post
```

The new sub_course page `sub_courses.new.html` form.

```
= form_for @sub_course, url: admin_sub_courses_path do |f|
  = f.label :title
  = f.text_field :title
  = f.label :description
  = f.text_field :description
  = f.submit
```

When going to the sub course new page I see the error `No route matches [POST] "/admin/sub_courses/new"`

My `sub_course_controller.rb` looks like this:

```
def new
    @course = Course.find(params.require(:course_id))
    @sub_course = @course.sub_course.new
  end

  def create
    if @sub_course.save
      redirect_to admin_sub_courses_path, notice: "saved"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

And my routes looks like this:

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :courses, { :only => [:index, :new, :create, :edit, :destroy, :update, :show] }
    resources :sub_courses 
  end
```

How do I successfully create a sub_course thats automatically associated with its course from the original show page I came from?

Schema structure looks like this:

```
  create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "title"
    t.string "description"
    t.integer "sub_course_id"
  end

  create_table "sub_courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "question"
    t.string "possible_answer"
    t.string "correct_answer"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "course_id"
  end
```

After running rake routes for sub courses:

```
admin_sub_courses GET    /admin/sub_courses(.:format)                                                             admin/sub_courses#index
                          POST   /admin/sub_courses(.:format)                                                             admin/sub_courses#create
     new_admin_sub_course GET    /admin/sub_courses/new(.:format)                                                         admin/sub_courses#new
    edit_admin_sub_course GET    /admin/sub_courses/:id/edit(.:format)                                                    admin/sub_courses#edit
         admin_sub_course GET    /admin/sub_courses/:id(.:format)                                                         admin/sub_courses#show
                          PATCH  /admin/sub_courses/:id(.:format)                                                         admin/sub_courses#update
                          PUT    /admin/sub_courses/:id(.:format)                                                         admin/sub_courses#update
                          DELETE /admin/sub_courses/:id(.:format)                                                         admin/sub_courses#destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would check the result of `rake routes |grep sub_courses`.

At a first glance, though,  it seems to me there is a problem of value assignment in the `sub_course` controller.
I would try to refactor it as follows:

```
  before_action :set_course, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
     @sub_course = @course.sub_courses.new 
  end

  def create
     @sub_course = @course.sub_courses.new(sub_course_params)
     if @sub_course.create!(sub_course_params)
      redirect_to admin_sub_courses_path, notice: "saved"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

private

def sub_course_params
  params.require(:sub_course).permit(:title, :description, :question, :possible_answer, :correct_answer, :course_id)
end

def set_course
 @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
end
```

As you see, I removed the line with `Course.find(params.require(:course_id))` with the the correct syntax for finding a record through a params.
The `params.require` syntax is instead used by strong parameters, which need to be defined, in order to actually persist data from forms into records in the database.

See https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

I then moved the `@course` assignment into a private method `set_course`   This way the assignment is done just once and is shared by the methods that need it.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue for me unfortunately. Still encountering the error `No route matches [POST] "/admin/sub_courses/new"`

I thought #new was never suppose to be a POST? - I updated the initial post with the grep routes